# Regular expression to extract a numeric value on a changing position within a variable string

Tags: php, regex

How can I extract the bold numeric part of a string, when the most of the string can change? */data/* is always present and followed by the relevant, variable, numeric part (in this case **123456**).

differentcontentLocationhttps://example.com/api/result/13548/*data*/**123456**differentstuffincludingwhitespacesandnewlines8484

```
$str = "differentcontentLocationhttps://example.com/api/result/13548/data/123456differentstuffincludingwhitespacesandnewlines8484";

$str2 = "differentcontentLocationhttps://example.com/api/result/13548/data/123456";
```

In this example I need **`123456`**. The only constant parts in the string are *`/data/`* and maybe the first part of the URL, like https://.

```
preg_match("@/data/([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)@siU", $str, $matches);
```

Results in `Array ( [0] => /data/123456d [1] => 123456 [2] => d )`, what would be acceptable. But if there's nothing following the relevant numeric part, like in `$str2`, this expression fails. I've tried to make the tailing part optional with `preg_match("@/ads/([0-9]+)(([^0-9]+)?)@siU", $x, $matches);`, but it fails, too; returning only the first number of the numeric part.

Comment: Use `@/data/([0-9]+)@i`. The `U` modifier is really not helping you and makes the regex more complex than it needs to be. See http://ideone.com/IUQMBS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `U` greediness swapping modifier makes all greedy subpattern lazy here, you should remove it together with `([^0-9]+)`. You also do not need DOTALL modifier because there is no `.` in your pattern whose behavior could be modified with that `s` flag.

```
preg_match("@/data/([0-9]+)@i", $str, $matches);
```

Now, the pattern will match:

- `/data/` - a sequence of literal chars
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ digits (same as `(\d+)`)

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/IUQMBS).

```
$str = "differentcontentLocationhttps://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/api/result/13548/data/123456differentstuffincludingwhitespacesandnewlines8484";
$str2 = "differentcontentLocationhttps://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/api/result/13548/data/123456";
preg_match("@/data/([0-9]+)@i", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches); // Array ( [0] => /data/123456  [1] => 123456  )
preg_match("@/data/([0-9]+)@i", $str2, $matches2);
print_r($matches2); // Array ( [0] => /data/123456  [1] => 123456  )
```

Comment: I've realized after your first comment, that the U modifier is causing troubles. Your pattern works in the real world perfectly. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes. I also added links to the SO Regex documentation describing those modifiers you do not need.